# C Programming: Error while printing all lines containing a specific word from a text file

Tags: c, text

I want to print all lines from input file "1PGB.pdb" to a file "out" containing the word "ATOM".

Following is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
  {
    char line[1000];
    char *pch;
    char c[5] = "ATOM";
    char buff[5];

    FILE *fp = fopen("1PGB.pdb", "r");
    FILE *op = fopen("out", "w");

    if(fp == NULL || op == NULL)
       {
          fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file.");
          exit(1);
       }
    else 
       {
         while (fgets(c, sizeof(line), fp) != 0)
           {
              if((pch = strstr (c, buff))!= 0)
              fprintf(op, "%s\n", c);
           }
       }

   fclose(fp);
   fclose(op);
 }
```

Error: It prints all the lines from "1PGB.pdb" file to the "out" file.

Few lines of the 1PGB.pdb file are as follows:

```
REMARK 525    HOH A  79        DISTANCE =  8.99 ANGSTROMS                       
DBREF  1PGB A    2    56  UNP    P06654   SPG1_STRSG     228    282             
SEQRES   1 A   56  MET THR TYR LYS LEU ILE LEU ASN GLY LYS THR LEU LYS          
SEQRES   2 A   56  GLY GLU THR THR THR GLU ALA VAL ASP ALA ALA THR ALA          
SEQRES   3 A   56  GLU LYS VAL PHE LYS GLN TYR ALA ASN ASP ASN GLY VAL          
SEQRES   4 A   56  ASP GLY GLU TRP THR TYR ASP ASP ALA THR LYS THR PHE          
SEQRES   5 A   56  THR VAL THR GLU                                              
FORMUL   2  HOH   *24(H2 O)                                                     
HELIX    1   1 ALA A   23  ASP A   36  1                                  14    
SHEET    1  S1 4 LEU A  12  ALA A  20  0                                        
SHEET    2  S1 4 MET A   1  GLY A   9 -1                                        
SHEET    3  S1 4 LYS A  50  GLU A  56  1                                        
SHEET    4  S1 4 GLU A  42  ASP A  46 -1                                        
CRYST1   36.633   36.633   79.254  90.00  90.00 120.00 P 31 2 1      6          
ORIGX1      1.000000  0.000000  0.000000        0.00000                         
ORIGX2      0.000000  1.000000  0.000000        0.00000                         
ORIGX3      0.000000  0.000000  1.000000        0.00000                         
SCALE1      0.027298  0.015760  0.000000        0.00000                         
SCALE2      0.000000  0.031521  0.000000        0.00000                         
SCALE3      0.000000  0.000000  0.012618        0.00000                         
ATOM      1  N   MET A   1      12.969  18.506  30.954  1.00 15.93           N  
ATOM      2  CA  MET A   1      13.935  18.529  29.843  1.00 17.40           C  
ATOM      3  C   MET A   1      13.138  18.692  28.517  1.00 14.65           C  
ATOM      4  O   MET A   1      12.007  18.222  28.397  1.00 13.04           O  
ATOM      5  CB  MET A   1      14.733  17.216  29.882  1.00 20.72           C
```

Comment: `c` needs to be 5 characters long; `ATOM` plus terminating zero.

Comment: Thanks to point out, edited that.

Comment: make it char * c = "ATOM"; You should also check the order of parameters to strstr.

Comment: I see two other things. You're searching for `c` in `buff` instead of `line`, and you should not append a newline when writing; it's already in the string.

Comment: `while (fgets(c, sizeof(line), fp) != 0)` must be wrong, it should read into `line` shouldn't it? That makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char c[4] = "ATOM";` should be `char c[5] = "ATOM";`, there is an implicit `'\0'` at the end of each C string. `char c[] = "ATOM";` or `const char *c = "ATOM";` are also possible.

`while (fgets(c, sizeof(line), fp) != 0)` should be `while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != 0)`, you want to write into the `line` buffer.

`if((pch = strstr (c, buff))!= 0)` should be `if ((pch = strstr(line, c))!= 0)`. You are looking for the string `c` (containing "ATOM") in the string in `line`.

`fprintf(op, "%s\n", c);` should be `fprintf(op, "%s", line);` if you want to write the line into the file. `fprintf(op, "%s", pch);` could also be possible if you want to write the rest of the line beginning at the "ATOM" into the file. @Tom Zych pointed out that there is already a new line in the string from fgets, so you do not need to add another one in `fprintf`. You can also use `fputs` in this case.

Comment: I seem to recall that `fgets()` retains the newline at the end, yes? So the output should not add another one. `fputs()` will do.